# get <div> ID which has been set dynamically by setAttribute() using getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Creating checkbox for each book in array and setting id as it's respective title. Now i need to get the id of a particular check using getElementId(). My         document.getElementById(id); is not working obviously. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
     books.forEach(b => {
        const btn = document.createElement('input')
        btn.type = 'checkbox'
        btn.setAttribute("id",b.title)
        perhiscontainer.appendChild(btn)
    })


    var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
```

Comment: Can you add some more code to your question, Where is the id variable in `document.getElementById(id)` coming from?

Comment: id is the dummy value i used just to show how i used getElementById

Comment: The code you are using should work. But make sure that b.title is a valid id. Check https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing b.title inside getElementById() will retrieve dynamically created  ID

```
books.forEach(b => {
    const btn = document.createElement('input')
    btn.type = 'checkbox'
    btn.setAttribute("id",b.title)
    perhiscontainer.appendChild(btn)
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(b.title);
})
```